# Sort In MDX Query not work

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx, olap

I use `SSAS` and `SQL Server 2008R2`

I use AdventureWorkDW dimensional Database.

I write this query :

```
Select
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
order(
        [Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory],
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
        asc
    ) on rows
From [Adventure Works]
```

I got result like this :

[image]

also i write this query :

```
Select
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
non empty order(
                crossjoin(
                    [Product].[Category].[Category],
                    [Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory]
                     ),
                [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
                desc
                ) on rows
From [Adventure Works]
```

And result is not sorted also :

[image]

Why result was not sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query (2012sql):

```
Select
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
order(
        [Product].[Product Categories].[Subcategory],
        [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
        basc
    ) on rows
From [Adventure Works]
```

The problem was I think because data [was hierarchical and with](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx) `basc` you sort just with Amount.

> The Order function can either be hierarchical (as specified by using
>   the ASC or DESC flag) or nonhierarchical (as specified by using the
>   BASC or BDESC flag

Result (2012sql):

```
|                GG | INTERNET SALES AMOUNT |
|-------------------|-----------------------|
|            Lights |                (null) |
|             Locks |                (null) |
|          Panniers |                (null) |
|             Pumps |                (null) |
|        Bib-Shorts |                (null) |
|            Tights |                (null) |
|   Bottom Brackets |                (null) |
|            Brakes |                (null) |
|            Chains |                (null) |
|         Cranksets |                (null) |
|       Derailleurs |                (null) |
|             Forks |                (null) |
|        Handlebars |                (null) |
|          Headsets |                (null) |
|   Mountain Frames |                (null) |
|            Pedals |                (null) |
|       Road Frames |                (null) |
|           Saddles |                (null) |
|    Touring Frames |                (null) |
|            Wheels |                (null) |
|             Socks |             $5,106.32 |
|          Cleaners |             $7,218.60 |
|              Caps |            $19,688.10 |
|            Gloves |            $35,020.70 |
|             Vests |            $35,687.00 |
|        Bike Racks |            $39,360.00 |
|       Bike Stands |            $39,591.00 |
|   Hydration Packs |            $40,307.67 |
|           Fenders |            $46,619.58 |
| Bottles and Cages |            $56,798.19 |
|            Shorts |            $71,319.81 |
|           Jerseys |           $172,950.68 |
|           Helmets |           $225,335.60 |
|   Tires and Tubes |           $245,529.32 |
|     Touring Bikes |         $3,844,801.05 |
|    Mountain Bikes |         $9,952,759.56 |
|        Road Bikes |        $14,520,584.04 |
```